# <DIV> boxes overlapping when adding a third

Tags: html, css

First of all. I´m kind of a rookie when it comes to coding webdesign. Last time I made a website was 20 years ago, and I can say that a lot has happened :-)

To the topic. I´m trying to create a couple of boxes in . I want them all to stay in the middle with a Little space between them. 
They need to go down in a row like this:

[*] [*]
[*] [*]

My problem is that when i add my third and fourth they overlap the top boxes!

Link to code on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2cZtH/7/ `enter code here`

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/2cZtH/10/) what you want?

Comment: See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/2cZtH/12/)

Comment: something Went wrong with the first fiddle. Look at this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/65ezbbco/

As you can se, the right one is overlapping the top one. I want to position the overlapped box right under the top one...........

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Top Left Content
        </td>
        <td>
            Top Right Content
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Bottom Left Content (Blank)
        </td>
        <td>
            Bottom Right Content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Put your `div`s in the table cells, and remove their absolute positioning property as this will prevent the table cells from sizing properly.

Comment: something Went wrong with the first fiddle. Look at this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/65ezbbco/

As you can se, the right one is overlapping the top one. I want to position the overlapped box right under the top one...........

Comment: @RickardFransson I edited my post so the table arranges them in the shape (I think) you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/2cZtH/8/

You shouldn't really be using position:absolute for this ideally, that takes them out of the DOM and you have to position them all manually. You can give them a width of a % of the containing div and float them left for the same effect with much more ease. :)

```
div { width:25%; float:left;   border-radius: 25px; margin-right:2.5%;
  border: 2px solid #A9B8C2;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ECECEC; }
```

Edit: Of course you can use a set width if you know the width of the containing div.

Comment: something Went wrong with the first fiddle. Look at this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/65ezbbco/

As you can se, the right one is overlapping the top one. I want to position the overlapped box right under the top one...........

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to understand your code, is this something you are trying to create
http://jsfiddle.net/2cZtH/11/

I created a simple box that is repeated. Using `display:inline-block;` stacks them in order and causes a line break when it reaches the end of the viewport.

If you are just trying to create three columns using `float:left` is all you need.
http://jsfiddle.net/2cZtH/15/

Comment: something Went wrong with the first fiddle. Look at this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/65ezbbco/

As you can se, the right one is overlapping the top one. I want to position the overlapped box right under the top one...........

Answer (score 0):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/2cZtH/14/)

Your HTML code had many problems which made it to malfunction.I have changed your code a little. See below for the changed code. Please replace your HTML with this one.

The main problem with your CSS was that you was using `position:absolute;` which made it look like that. So i've changed that to `position:relative`.

You can **read more about CSS positioning** [here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)..

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        <p id="rcorners"> <a href="#" class="fillthediv">
    <img alt="Non-technical" style="float: left;margin-right:10px; width:128px; height:128px" src="images/Artiklar/Alger.jpg" />
    <span class="fulldivhead"> Alger i våra kar</span>
    <br /><br/>
    <span class="fulldivp"> En artikel som beskriver ingående de vanligaste algerna i våra akvarier. Med många bra bilder tillsammans med Beskrivning/Orsak/Bekämpning gör denna artikel till 
    förmodligen den mest omfattande på webben.
    <br/><br/>
    </span>
    </a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p id="rcorners"> <a href="#" class="fillthediv">
    <img alt="Non-technical" style="float: left;margin-right:10px; width:128px; height:128px" src="images/Artiklar/Alger.jpg" />
    <span class="fulldivhead">De vanligaste växtbristerna</span>
    <br /><br/>
    <span class="fulldivp"> 
    <br/><br/>
    </span>
    </a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p id="rcorners"> <a href="#" class="fillthediv">
    <img alt="Non-technical" style="float: left;margin-right:10px; width:128px; height:128px" src="images/Artiklar/Alger.jpg" />
    <span class="fulldivhead">De vanligaste växtbristerna</span>
    <br /><br/>
    <span class="fulldivp"> 
    <br/><br/>
    </span>
    </a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks all. But I think i was misunderstood. My boxes is going to sit next to the other. Centered in the mittle. Under there us going in to new boxes. So to sum. To boxes centered in the top. Two boxes centered right under the top boxes. In perfect align.

Comment: Follow this link and look at the Picture (i´m no Picasso tho)

http://forumbilder.se/EBATQ/box

@bytesized

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! By making the right box relative and edit margin-right plus margin-top. Plus link in clear after code. Thanks!